# Triggers (for generated code) produce error when doing restore data on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, restore

I had backup my data on postgresql db into 'new_backup_data.sql' using  `pg_dump --column-inserts -h localhost -U postgres micro -a -F p > /tmp/new_backup_data.sql`, then I want to restore the data  on different database which is already have same schema tables,trigger. `psql -U postgres micro < /tmp/new_backup_data.sql`

But the trigger always make it fail. Here is the error:

```
QUERY:  SELECT                                  LPAD(cast(cast(substring(registration_code, 10) AS integer) + 1 AS varchar), 4, '0')
    FROM t_registration
    ORDER BY id
        DESC LIMIT 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.generate_registration_code() line 7 at SQL statement
ERROR:  relation "t_registration" does not exist
LINE 2:     FROM t_registration
                 ^
QUERY:  SELECT                                  LPAD(cast(cast(substring(registration_code, 10) AS integer) + 1 AS varchar), 4, '0')
    FROM t_registration
    ORDER BY id
        DESC LIMIT 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.generate_registration_code() line 7 at SQL statement
ERROR:  relation "t_registration" does not exist
LINE 2:     FROM t_registration
                 ^
QUERY:  SELECT                                  LPAD(cast(cast(substring(registration_code, 10) AS integer) + 1 AS varchar), 4, '0')
    FROM t_registration
    ORDER BY id
        DESC LIMIT 1
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function public.generate_registration_code() line 7 at SQL statement
ERROR:  relation "t_registration" does not exist
LINE 2:     FROM t_registration
```

Here is some my query when  tried to open the backup sql file:

```
INSERT INTO public.t_registration (id, created_by, created_date, last_modified_by, last_modified_date, is_active, registration_code, registration_type_code, app_id, app_code, account_code) VALUES (94, 'Admin', '2020-07-16 09:04:32.095', 'Admin', '2020-07-16 09:04:32.095', true, 'REG2007160001', 'R2007001', 1, 'APP202007001', NULL);
```

When I run the query manually via PG admin it works and no problem with the trigger, but why when i restore it always produce those errors?

Note : My trigger is used for generate pattern of unique code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the top of the dump file. I'm guessing you have something like `SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);`  This blanks the `search_path`. Since the table name in the function is not schema qualified it is not found. The pgAdmin case works as the `search_path` is set there. FYI, the dump file is using `COPY` to pull in the data. That still fires the triggers though.

**UPDATE**. To fix schema qualify the table name in the function.

Comment: Yeah on my top of the dump file has 'SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);'. So what should i do to make it works? The dump file I used is using 'insert' btw . i used '--column-inserts'

Comment: The `--column-inserts` was not include in your question example. I would add it to the example. The fix is to edit the function and schema qualify the the table name. See [this](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/A_Guide_to_CVE-2018-1058:_Protect_Your_Search_Path) for why that is important and necessary in recent versions of Postgres.